# Working of nutch server in distributed mode

Tags: nutch

I would like to know how nutch server works actually in a distributed environment? Whether it use a listener for incoming crawl requests or it is a continuously running server?

Comment: FYI : Link to more details regarding this : http://www.mail-archive.com/user@nutch.apache.org/msg14958.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nutch REST API is built using Apache CXF framework and JAX-RS. The Nutch Server uses an embedded Jetty Server to service the http requests.

You can find out more about CXF and Jetty here (http://cxf.apache.org/docs/overview.html)

Comment: To put it right,my query is whether this acts as a listener for incoming crawl requests and trigger nutch slave nodes on demand OR is it continuously running as a distributed server ?

Comment: And whether we can use Nutch server in a distributed environment(with Nutch 1.x distributed with hadoop) ? Please reply

Comment: The Nutch server it self is not distributed, that would run on one machine waiting for http requests. Once a request is received it will start the respective Nutch Job requested (which might be distributed ex- fetch job).

Comment: I did not quite understand what do you mean by "can we use Nutch server in distributed env". Why not give it a try ?

Comment: Yep.Ive tried.Seems like working . Do you have any idea how to give generated segment as argument of succeeding fetch phase in nutch rest ?

Comment: If you are running all jobs using the REST API the specifying the crawlId should be fine, the fetch job will then pick the latest segment. But if you want to manually specify the segment path, pass a key:value pair in the args {} of the request where key="segment" value=<path to your segment>. 

Have a look here for further reference : https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch_1.X_RESTAPI/RunningJobsTutorial

Comment: I'm intending to run nutch using REST api itself. Am creating a configuration and using that confId in each request. But fetch phase doesn't automatically pickup the latest segment. More details can be found in mailing list http://www.mail-archive.com/user@nutch.apache.org/msg14958.html

Comment: In another note am using nutch 1.12(so REST 1.x)